# Constructing a query that has some calculated values, unexpectedly changes the # of rows

Tags: neo4j

I have a query that looks like this:

```
MATCH (d:Project)<-[:USING]-(t:TestRun)-[:ON]->(o:OS)
WITH t, o, d
RETURN count(t) as Number_Of_Runs, o.name as OS_Name, d.name as Source_Branch, ROUND(avg(t.failing_tests)/t.tests_run * 100) as Average_Pct_Failing,
ROUND(avg(t.passing_tests)/t.tests_run * 100) as Average_Pct_Passing,
ROUND(avg(t.skipped_tests)/t.tests_run * 100) as Average_Pct_Skipped
```

When I run only a portion of the query:

```
MATCH (d:Project)<-[:USING]-(t:TestRun)-[:ON]->(o:OS)
WITH t, o, d
RETURN count(t) as Number_Of_Runs, o.name as OS_Name, d.name as Source_Branch
```

I get back 2 rows, which is what I expect, given the data that I have (1 Project node, and 2 OS nodes, with some # of TestRun nodes related to each OS nodes).

However, when I add on the various ROUND(AVG(...)) parts, I end up with a lot more rows.  I think I'm getting additional rows for each distinct combination of all of the returned values.

What I would like is to keep getting the 2 returned rows, with the addition of the columns containing the calculations.  I am not sure what I need to do to change the query to accomplish that.

If there is some additional information that I need to share to make this clearer, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
MATCH (d:Project)<-[:USING]-(t:TestRun)-[:ON]->(o:OS)
RETURN count(t) AS Number_Of_Runs,
  o.name AS OS_Name, d.name AS Source_Branch,
  ROUND(avg(toFloat(t.failing_tests)/t.tests_run)* 100) AS Average_Pct_Failing,
  ROUND(avg(toFloat(t.passing_tests)/t.tests_run)* 100) AS Average_Pct_Passing,
  ROUND(avg(toFloat(t.skipped_tests)/t.tests_run)* 100) AS Average_Pct_Skipped;
```

[Here is a console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=p4cid) demonstrating this query.

There was a very subtle problem with your original query. Your original terms using the aggregation function `avg()` did not include all uses of `t`, so they were not really aggregating at all.

Comment: Yes - works perfectly.   That is a very subtle difference indeed.  I sat here looking at my version and yours for about 15 minutes before it clicked.  Thank you!